# Redux-saga not able to read react-native

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-redux, redux-saga

I am trying a read a **Image File** using `react-native-fs` in react-native.

Below is my generator function in **saga.js:**

```
function* uploadCardLogo(logo, userId) {

  console.log("uploading card logo"); //being logged
  const storageRef = firebase.storage().ref('${userId}').child("mycards/logos/");
  console.log("storage ref fetched " + logo.uri); //being logged

  const cardLogo = yield call(RNFS.readFile, logo.uri); // Not throwing any errors
  console.log("reading file done") // Not being logged

  const logoStorageUrl = yield call([storageRef, storageRef.put], cardLogo);
  console.log("Logo has been update = ${logoStorageUrl}");
  return logoStorageUrl;
}
```

As you can see, I am not able to read the Image file nor am I getting any errors, Can anyone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

**EDIT:**

Below is my function from which `uploadCardLogo` is being called:

```
function* uploadCard(action) {
  console.log("about to upload card");
  console.log(action.card);

  try{
      const userId = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
      const database = firebase.database();
      const logoStorageUrl = yield call(uploadCardLogo, action.card.logo, userId);
      const ref = database.ref('users/'+userId+'/myCards');
      const result = yield call([ref, ref.set], action.card);
      console.log("Card Added To Realtime Database");
      yield put({type: CARD_UPLOADED, card: action.card});
      console.log("about to update app state");
  }
  catch(error) {
    const error_message = {code: error.code, message: error.message};
    yield put({type: CARD_UPLOAD_ERROR, error: error_message})
  }
}
```

Comment: "`// Not throwing any errors`" wrap your code with `try-catch` just to be sure. Also you could race `RNFS.readfile` call with `delay` to check if reading a file for some reason doesn't take too long. `const { cardLogo } = yield race({ cardLogo: call(...), timeout: delay(5000)}); if (!cardLogo){ // timeout logic}`

Comment: @Jois: could it be a context issue? What happens if you replace `yield call(RNFS.readFile, ...)` with `yield call([RNFS, RNFS.readFile], ...)`?
See docs here: https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/api/#callcontext-fn-args

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what `RNFS.readFile` is but in order to catch the error you have to wrap your `call` into a try-catch block:

```
try {
  const cardLogo = yield call(RNFS.readFile, logo.uri);
} catch (error) {
  console.log(error);
}
```

If you don't do this here the error will be propagated to the parent saga and if there is a try-catch block it will catch it.

Comment: I do have a try catch in the parent saga thats the reason I am not catching it here but still I am not getting any errors

Comment: RNFS is just variable

Comment: I mean what's stands behind it. Is it a native module? Is it returning a promise or it works with callbacks?

Comment: Edited the question and added the function which calls uploadCardLogo