# How to a read a Image in react-native

Tags: react-native

How to read an Image file from camera roll in react-native? I tried reading a file using `react-native-fs` [You can find the issue I am facing using this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48263915/redux-saga-not-able-to-read-react-native).

Comment: How would you like to read it? Like, you want to display all images in your phone, then select one for you to upload?

Comment: Select one and upload it

Answer (score 0):

I assume you already know how to select images from your `CameralRoll`, simply use the `CameraRoll` API from `react-native` module. If this is the way you select images, then your image uri should look like this: `asset-library://asset/...`

Then, you should probably use `react-native-fetch-blob` module:

```
npm install --save react-native-fetch-blob
```

and

```
react-native link
```

In the file where your `uploadImage` function is defined (I assume you use firebase as your backend because I saw that in your other question):

```
import RNFetchBlob from 'react-native-fetch-blob';

const Blob = RNFetchBlob.polyfill.Blob;
const fs = RNFetchBlob.fs;
window.XMLHttpRequest = RNFetchBlob.polyfill.XMLHttpRequest;
window.Blob = Blob;

function uploadImage(photo) {
    const ref = firebase.storage().ref('path/to/destination');
    let photoBlob = null;

    let imageFile = RNFetchBlob.wrap(photos[i]);
    Blob.build(imageFile, { type: 'image/jpg' })
        .then((blob) => {
            photoBlob = blob;
            return ref.put(blob, { contentType: 'image/jpg' });
        })
        .then(() => photoBlob.close())
        .catch((error) => console.log(error));
}
```

All set. But if you're not using `CameraRoll` to select pictures (uri will look different), it is ok, simply pass the path of the photo you want to upload to this function and leave everything else the same

Comment: I am trying to do this using redux-saga and its not working You can view the question using the following link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48274224/redux-saga-function-not-being-called